# android FAB анимация

Tags: android, android-animation

в окне TabHost с 2 вкладками и Floating Action Button. fab должна анимированно закрываться при переключении на первую вкладку и появляться на второй. при старте кнопка скрыта

```
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fabAddImages"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_gravity="end"
        android:layout_marginTop="370dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_menu_add1"
        />  


tabHost.setOnTabChangedListener(new TabHost.OnTabChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onTabChanged(String tabId) {
        if(tabId.equals("tab_text"))
            fabAddImages.hide();

        else if(tabId.equals("tab_image"))
            fabAddImages.show();
    }
});
```

беда в том что при первом переключении на вторую вкладку кнопка появляется без анимации, дальше нормально

Answer (score 0):

Очень похоже на специфику реализации анимации.
Элемент, который ни разу не отображался, не может "красиво" появиться.

Попробуйте изначально скрывать его другим способом, не через `GONE` в разметке.  Возможно, программно.

Comment: поставил VISIBLE в разметке, а в onCreate hide(), эффекта не дало

Comment: В onCreate еще ничего не отображается, поэтому и эффекта нет.